# Subfigures in Springer's book monograph class give error (but do work)

Tags: floats, subfloats, books, sv-classes, springer

I'm using Springer's latex files to create a monograph book. The template can be found here:

https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation

When trying to use subfigures the document is compiled as expected but there is an error: Environment subfigure undefined. This is the code I'm using (in Overleaf btw):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% book.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% sample root file for the chapters of your "monograph"
%
% Use this file as a template for your own input.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Springer-Verlag %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% RECOMMENDED %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide

%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage{courier}
%
\usepackage{type1cm}         

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom

\usepackage{newtxtext}       % 
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font

% see the list of further useful packages
% in the Reference Guide

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{figure}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{figure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Some random caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have tried to use the subcaption package but this removes the formatting of the captions of all figures. Can someone provide some hints as how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please read about [Minimal Working Example] and edit your post accordingly. As it is, your code doesn't compile and we don't know which relevant packages you're using. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `caption` and `subcaption` packages are not compatible with `svmono`. But `subfig` is, provided you load it with the `caption=false` option.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% book.tex %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% sample root file for the chapters of your "monograph"
%
% Use this file as a template for your own input.
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Springer-Verlag %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


% RECOMMENDED %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide

%\usepackage{mathptmx}
%\usepackage{helvet}
%\usepackage{courier}
%
%\usepackage{type1cm}        % don't use it
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation
\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files
\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom

\usepackage{newtxtext}       % 
\usepackage[varvw]{newtxmath}       % selects Times Roman as basic font

% see the list of further useful packages
% in the Reference Guide
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter Heading}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\subfloat[Subcaption]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\quad
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}}
\caption{Some random caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I added subcaptions (one empty just by way of example.

If you don't need subcaptions or at least the letter, just place the images how you'd like to:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}\quad
\includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{example-image}
\caption{Some random caption}
\label{fig1}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, this solves my problem! Just one remaining question about the subcaptions: can you provide the code for that as well for completeness?

Comment: @RudderDuck Didn't I? `\subfloat[Subcaption text]{graphic material}`

Comment: I couldn't find it in the code but that snippet explains it. Thanks again.

Comment: I have edited the answer to actually produce the output that is shown in the image (including subfigure)!